# Multiple selections multiplied by an input value jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm starting to learn jQuery and need a bit of help to point me in the right direction.

I am trying to make a cost calculator that has multiple drop down selections that if selected will be multiplied by the number in an input box.

e.g. Company one cost per unit for one service is 1.0, for two service 1.5 and three service 2.0. This needs to be multiplied by the number of units in input and the total shown in a div below.

My HTML is below

```
<form>
    <div>
        <label>Company</label>
        <p>
            <select class="dropbox" id="comapny">
                <option value="Select">Select</option>
                <option value="1">Company one</option>
                <option value="2">Company two</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Service</label>
                <p>
                    <select class="dropbox" id="service">
                        <option value="Select">Select</option>
                        <option value="1">One service</option>
                        <option value="2">Two service</option>
                        <option value="3">Three service</option>
                    </select>
                    <p>
                        </div>
                          <div>
                            <label>Unit</label>
                            <p>
                                <input id="unit"></input>
                                <p>
                                    </div>
                                   <div>
                                        <label>Reduction</label>
                                        <p>
                                            <select class="dropbox">
                                                <option value="Select">Select</option>
                                                <option value="Yes ">Yes</option>
                                                <option value="No">No</option>
                                            </select>
                                           </div> 
                                           </form>
                                            <p>
                                                <div>bill amount updated here</div>
```

My code (proberly nothing like what it needs to be)

```
$(.dropbox).on('change', function() {
var comapny = "",
    service = "",
    unit = .val,


$.each(function() {

});

var sum = service * unit = toal
```

});

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D4RgB/)

Any suggestions on how I should approach this and what functions I will need to learn to achieve this would be really appreciated. 
I have read up on using parseInt and var but am really struggling bringing it all together.

A big thanks to any help in advance.

Comment: Hmm, your HTML seems to be missing some closing tags.

Comment: Sorry I was sloppy. I have now edited. Hope I got them all.

Comment: post your code in [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: jsFiddle added as an edit. Is it ok to do it that way or better as a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".dropbox").on("change", function() {
      var unit = $("#unit").val();
      if (unit != "")
          alert($(this).val() * unit);
   });
});
```

If you aren't populating the `Unit` textbox then I would also consider attaching this to the text box change so it updates when values are typed in.

This should give you enough information to adapt it to suit your needs.

The key is `$("#unit").val();`. This gets the value from the associated input / drop down etc based on ID (`#`) or class (`.`). To get the company value for instance you would use: `$("#comapny").val();`

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peVPr/1/)

Comment: Thank you this a great starting point for me. From this could I add another var for the company selections to make the unit cost per service relevant to what company is selected?

Comment: Thanks I think I should be able work it out from here. (or give it a good try anyway)